# How do I show annotations on my Google Chart that extracts data from a Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-visualization

I have a Google Chart that displays some data.

Here is the HTML -

```
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Here is the CSS -

```
html,
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#chart {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Here is the JS -

```
google.charts.load('current', {
    'packages': ['corechart']
});

google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    var query = new     google.visualization.Query("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wLbWMwwu_bXcpxm8TlkNtkR4gbeqz_o8CuRzdDQMUaM/gviz/tq?gid=799372846&range=A:B");

    query.send(handleQueryResponse);
}

function handleQueryResponse(response) {
    var data = response.getDataTable();

    var chartAreaHeight = data.getNumberOfRows() * 10;

    var chartHeight = chartAreaHeight + 70;

    var options = {
        title: "Andaman & Nicobar Islands",
        legend: "none",
        vAxis: {
            title: "Year",
            format: "0",
        },
        hAxis: {
            title: "Rainfall (in mm)"
        },
        height: chartHeight,
        chartArea: {
            height: chartAreaHeight,
            top: "100",
            right: "100",
            bottom: "100",
            left: "100"
        }
    };

    var chart = new     google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById("chart"));

    chart.draw(data, options);
};

window.onresize = function (event) {
    chart.draw(data, options);
};
```

Now, I want to display annotations beside the bars displaying the value of that bar. How do I do that?

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yashghelani/etpz323o/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to add annotations, add a column for the annotation text, directly after the column with the values.

in the following example, a `DataView` is used to add a calculated column for the annotations.

also, the `resize` function needs to be included in the same scope as the `chart`.
in the fiddle provided, an error will occur when the window is resized,
as the `chart`, `data`, and `options` variables are not available.

see following, working example...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['corechart']
});

google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var query = new google.visualization.Query("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wLbWMwwu_bXcpxm8TlkNtkR4gbeqz_o8CuRzdDQMUaM/gviz/tq?gid=799372846&range=A:B");
  query.send(handleQueryResponse);
}

function handleQueryResponse(response) {
  var data = response.getDataTable();
  var chartAreaHeight = data.getNumberOfRows() * 10;
  var chartHeight = chartAreaHeight + 70;
  var options = {
    // add text style for annotation
    annotations: {
      textStyle: {
        fontSize: 8
      }
    },
    title: "Andaman & Nicobar Islands",
    legend: "none",
    vAxis: {
      title: "Year",
      format: "0"
    },
    hAxis: {
      title: "Rainfall (in mm)"
    },
    height: chartHeight,
    chartArea: {
      height: chartAreaHeight,
      top: "100",
      right: "100",
      bottom: "100",
      left: "100"
    }
  };

  // format data for annotation
  var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({pattern: '#,##0.0'});
  formatter.format(data, 1);

  // use view to add annotation column
  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0, 1, {
    calc: "stringify",
    sourceColumn: 1,
    type: "string",
    role: "annotation"
  }]);

  var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById("chart"));
  chart.draw(view, options);

  window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
    chart.draw(view, options);
  }, false);
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#chart {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Comment: I have a few more issues with this chart. Can you help me with them?

Comment: Can you check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/yashghelani/wveawwg3/) fiddle? I'm trying to create a feature in which when you select a region and request rainfall data for it, you'll get a Google Chart for that data. The problem is when I select any region and request data, it always creates a chart for the first region in the list. Can you check what the problem is? Sorry in advance for the ugly code. I'm a newbie to JS. I've commented the code though to help understand it better. Thanks :)

Comment: BTW, I've created a [separate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38201668/google-chart-is-not-displaying) for that problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You're a life saver:)